# System.Web.Services : is there password property in Context.User.Identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

just a small query

i m using .net web service and created simple login method

```
[WebMethod]
    public bool Login(string sUsername, string sPwd)
    {
        if (sUsername == Context.User.Identity.Name && **sPwd == "123456"**)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sUsername, true);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
```

is there any password property like "Context.User.Identity.Name" . or any other alternative

Please suggest if i am missing something

Comment: you want to achive windows authentication?? and there is no such protpery context.user.identity.password

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't make sense. The Context.User is set by the Forms Authentication module which relies on the information from the forms cookie. You, on the other hand, try to use the information to acually ISSUE the cookie.

This means that you effectively need the cookie to issue the cookie. This won't work.

Try to rethink the approach - you probably need an external data source, like a database or something, to validate your users against. In the database you will have both usernames and their passwords stored somehow.